# Loop broken by ssh running script aside

Tags: bash, ssh

I have a couple of machines to update some script on. I can do this with a small bash script on my side, which consists of one while loop for reading IPs from a list and calling scp for them. It works fine, but when I try to run updated script in a loop, it break the loop, although runs quite fine itself.

```
#!/bin/bash

cat ip_list.txt | while read i; do
    echo ${i}
    scp the_script root@${i}:/usr/sbin/ # works ok
    ssh root@${i} /usr/sbin/the_script  # works for a first IP, then breaks
done
```

Is this how it suppose to work? If so, how can I run a script remotely via ssh without breaking the loop?

Comment: Does /usr/bin/the_script return or block? If it blocks, the loop will not continue until the session is closed. Depending on the needed features, capistrano might be an alternative.

Comment: Putting things manually to `/usr/sbin/` doesn't sound very great to me. Have you considered packaging the script and providing it via a repo (be it rpm, deb or something else...)?

Comment: Of course normally everything is updated properly via RPM. It's just a one time thing. I hope.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Use this:

```
ssh -n root@${i} /usr/sbin/the_script  # works for a first IP, then breaks
```

The `-n` option tells `ssh` not to read from stdin. Otherwise, it reads stdin and passes it through to the network connection, and this consumes the rest of the input pipe.

Answer (score 1):

You need to change the ssh line like this

```
ssh root@${i} /usr/sbin/the_script  < /dev/null # works for a first IP, then breaks
```